# SQL QUERY HELP — Count the frequency of associated values given an input value

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

[HELP]

Hi everyone,

I have this table with the following columns:

| id | textID | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Hedonic |
| 2 | 1 | Negative feelings |
| 3 | 2 | Hedonic |
| 4 | 2 | Negative feelings |
| 5 | 2 | Fun |
| 6 | 2 | Motivation |
| 7 | 3 | Enjoy |
| 8 | 3 | Hedonic |
| 9 | 3 | Fun |
| 10 | 4 | Negative feelings |
| 11 | 4 | Pain |

And what I want to do is return the frequency of values associated with a given input value.

For example, given the value 'Hedonic', I want to return the count of values associated where 'hedonic' exists.
With the data from the table presented above, it should return the following table, for input 'Hedonic':

| value | count |
| --- | --- |
| Hedonic | 3 |
| Negative feelings | 2 |
| Fun | 2 |
| Enjoy | 1 |
| Motivation | 1 |

Can anyone help me?

I have no idea how to perform the SQL query... I've tried several approaches, but still no success.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `exists`:

```
select value, count(*)
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.textid = t.textid and t2.value = 'Hedonic'
             )
group by value;
```

Comment: thanks, it works! And there is another way to that without ```t2.value = 'Hedonic'```?

Comment: @RenatoSantos . . . "For example, given the value 'Hedonic', I want to return the count of values associated where 'hedonic' exists. "  That is the question you asked here.  If you have a different question, ask a new question.

Comment: you are right. My problem is using this SQL query on Metabase. I want to use a Field Filter to use instead of ```t2.values='value'```. The syntax of metabase to do that is: {{value}}, allowing to filter the selected value... {{value}} is mapping the column of database where is all the values (hedonic, fun, motivation, ...). In a normal SQL, it work as ```select value, count(*) from t where {{value}} group by value;```, given the count of presence of each value in column... But it's not what I want to do... I hope I have understood, and if it is possible to give me help I would appreciate it

Comment: if i replace ```t2.value = 'Hedonic'```with ```{{value}}```, it give me the count as I say in the previous comment... and not the table I want. I think it assumes the table ```annotation``` and not ```a2``` @GordonLinoff